# Susy not getting value from $grid-padding

Tags: html, css, grid, compass-sass, susy-compass

I have this coded on my layout sass file,

I'm using Susy Grid System and here's the values I set.

```
$total-columns: 12
$column-width: 60px
$gutter-width: 20px
$grid-padding: 10px
```

Problem is the container still gives me a 940px value instead of 960px.

Any solutions for this?.

Here's the full view.

```
$show-grid-backgrounds: true

@import "susy"

// For full Susy documentation, visit: http://susy.oddbird.net/tutorial/

$total-columns: 12
$column-width: 60px
$gutter-width: 20px
$grid-padding: 10px

.container
  // Include `container` if this element will contain a grid system.
  @include container($total-columns)
  // Apply our grid background stripes for development.
  @include susy-grid-background

header, #main-content, footer
  // Clearfix for full-width elements
  @include clearfix
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My output (copy/pasting your code) shows a width of `940px` and a padding of `10px`. Since padding is added to width, that is correct, and you have a final `960px` container. If you are using the `border-box` model, where padding is subtracted from the width, Susy can adjust for that, but you have to tell Susy that. You can either set the `$border-box-sizing` variable to `true` or use the built-in `border-box-sizing` mixin to apply the border-box model to all elements. See [the docs](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-border-box-mixin) for more.